Spring mvc functional endpoints and form validation
With the recents version of spring mvc, there is now an alternative to the classical spring mvc, the one with @Controller annotations.
The documentation of the functional enpoints is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc-functional.html
I like this new api, but some pieces seems to be lacking. In particular one that seems pretty important to be able to construct a web app.
The ability to communicate between endpoints while redirecting.
In classical spring mvc, when doing a redirect, we can add flash attribute into RedirectAttributes, which will endup setting something into the request session (I guess).
In the functional endpoints way of life, there is ways to access the session (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/function/ServerRequest.html#session()), but I don't see a way to add an attribute to the session only in the scope of the next redirect.
